# gcc address sanitizer core dump on error

Tags: gcc, coredump, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to do some debugging on a server on an issue that I suspect is related to a buffer overflow, so I tried to compile my code with `-fsanitize=address` to enable address sanitizing.

It compiled, and the resulting software runs. However, I'm trying to get a core dump when the address sanitizer detects an error since that is pretty much the only way I can get information out of the system due to the setup.

I am calling the software with `ASAN_OPTIONS=abort_on_error=1` prepended on the command line (using a shell script to do that), and have checked that `ulimit -c` gives unlimited as result, but it just won't produce a core dump.

What am I missing?

This is on an ubuntu 14.04 server with gcc version 4.8.4

EDIT: `sysctl kernel.core_pattern` gives back `kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P`. This probably means that apport is enabled (at least in some form). However, I have been able to get proper core files on this system from asserts and SIGFPEs in the software (that is where the suspicion of array overruns comes from).

Comment: Have you enabled `apport`? What's the value of `kernel.core_pattern` sysctl value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess, is this x64 target? Coredumps are disabled there to avoid dumping 16 TB shadow memory (see docs for `disable_coredump` [here](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/SanitizerCommonFlags) for details).

Newer versions of GCC/Clang [remove shadow from core by default](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/345) so that one could do something like

```
export ASAN_OPTIONS=abort_on_error=1:disable_coredump=0
```

but I'm afraid 4.8 is too old for this.

As an alternative suggestion, why backtraces are not enough for you? You could use `log_path` or `log_to_syslog` to preserve them if you do not have access to programs `stderr`.

NB: I [posted suggestion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/address-sanitizer/E6olsz4MvvE) to enable coredumps on all platforms.